# Why does <f:selectItems> with itemDisabled="#{expr}" not submit disabled selection?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I've come across a bug in our application where the following XHTML code doesn't work as I'd expect it!

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{nuv.rollen}" id="rollen" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:selectItems var="r" value="#{nuv.findRollen()}" itemLabel="#{r.label}" itemDisabled="#{nuv.isDisabledRolle(r)}" />
    <our:entityConverter /><!-- translates our entities back and forth -->
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

The setter `nuv.setRollen(List)` is called with an empty list (at least if all items are disabled) although all disabled items are checked in the UI. The code assumes that all elements have been deselected. If the items are enabled everything works fine.

Is this behavior normal? I'm very confused about this.

Comment: To explain this a little more... nuv.rollen has 10 elements... they are rendered disabled but checked... but upon submit the list is empty. I'd expect all 10 disabled but checked elements to be submitted.

Comment: Ups... where is the answer I just commented to? Deleted again? @BalusC

Comment: missing attribute `itemValue="#{r}"` for the `f:selectItems`?

Comment: No, that doesn't change anything. Remember: enabled items submit properly.